# Springboot JAR File 500s

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

So when I run my springboot application using 'gradlew bootRun', I have no issues and everything works. I tried compiling a .JAR file of my application, and the html/css loads, but when I try to execute a command that uses springboot, I receive a 500 message. I have included my build.gradle below, any suggestions?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.3.0'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'rest.Application'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.json:json:20171018")
    compile("org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.7")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path')
}
```

The exception thrown is this:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-10-02 11:44:05.885  INFO 27328 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Comment: How did you create the jar?

Comment: I created the jar by running 'gradlew bootJar'

Comment: If you get status 500, there should be an exception in the log. Show us the exception.

Comment: Hey guys, the exception is as follows: 
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-10-02 11:44:05.885  INFO 27328 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Comment: Close down your application. Then verify that nothing is listening on port 8080 (e.g. by opening http://localhost:8080 in a browser). If there is something there, you have to figure out what and shut it down. Alternatively, you can change the port for your application if you can't find a way to shut it down.